# How to unfold a Coq fixpoint by one iteration

Tags: coq

I have the following in my proof environment:

```
1 subgoal
a, b : nat
H : (fix loop (m : nat) : nat :=
       match (m - a) with
       | 0 => m
       | S m' => loop m'
       end) b = 0
G : (b - a) = 0
```

Clearly, H is equivalent to

```
       match (b - a) with
       | 0 => b
       | S m' => loop m'
       end = 0
```

Which would then allow me to rewrite using G.

But since it is trapped in there, represented as (m - a), I cannot rewrite using G.

How do I unfold a fixpoint out by one iteration?

Edit: The following code will set up the proof environment. Just ignore the admit statements. Your goal is not to prove the statement (which is trivial) but to "unfold" the fixpoint.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all.

Goal forall a b : nat,
  modn b a = 0 -> True.
Proof.
  intros a b H.
  unfold modn in H.
  destruct a.
    + admit.
    + simpl in H.
      assert ((b - a) = 0) as G.
      - admit.
      - unfold modn_rec in H.
```

Comment: `cbv` by default only affects the goal. Did you do something like `cbv in H.`?

Comment: Yes, I did try "cbv in H". Only expanded out the Z.sub. I think I understand what he was trying to say now, and it wasn't relevant, so I removed it from the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unfold a fixpoint you need to destruct its decreasing argument.

```
destruct b; simpl in H.
```

If you want to keep a single case, you'll have to prove the equality you mention in a separate lemma or `assert`ion.

```
assert (Hfix : (fix loop m := match ... end) b = match ... end)
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is good advice. It is often convenient to prove lemmas so that one can _rewrite_ expressions, instead of destructing arguments and do case analyses. It (arguably) also makes proofs more readable...

Comment: I don't think that works here. See, I have already "destructed" (b - a), that is why I know that b - a = 0. Just to be sure, I set up the proof environment and tried "destruct b; simpl in H". As I expected, all that did was split into two cases, the 0 case and the S x case, without unfolding the fixpoint. I added a way to set up the proof environment in the OP in case anyone wants to try. Also, it would certainly be nice if I could prove the assertion (Hfix : (fix loop m := match ... end) b = match ... end), but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: When I add at the end of your code `destruct b; simpl in H` I see, in subgoal 1, `H : 0 = 0`, and in subgoal 2, `H : match b.+1 - a with ...` (i.e., the `loop` got unfolded once in both cases).

Comment: Huh. It didn't seem to work for me before, but now it's working. Maybe I did something wrong, perhaps I just said destruct b; simpl. or something. Thanks!